# Throwing checked exception similar to "IllegalArgumentException"

Tags: java, exception

I have the following method where "a" is input from the user (network request to my service)

```
private ReturnObject getX(InputObject a) {
  ReturnObject ret = new ReturnObject();
  String s = a.getSomething();
  if (s != null) {
    ret.setSomething(s);
    return ret;
  }

  throws new CheckedExceptionSimilarToIllegalArgumentexception();
}
```

I'm calling this method internally so I'd like to handle the exception myself. In fact, I want to force everybody calling this method to handle this exception.

In my case, if the exception is thrown I want to catch it, inform the user that they did not set the appropriate field in the request & end the request.

I don't want to be returning nulls and then checking if the method returned null, that's really ugly.

However, I can't seem to find a checked exception similar to IllegalArgumentException and I don't want to create a new exception either. This seems like a very common scenario and I'm surprised I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You could return an `Optional`.

Comment: You could return a Guava `Optional`.

Comment: There's a Java.lang.NoSuchFieldException which could indicate that the field doesn't exist to the user?

Comment: NoSuchFieldException seems more appropriate when using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding `@NotNull` to the input argument.  This way a tool such as findbug or IntelliJ can warn you when you write the code not to pass a `null` value in the first place.

In that case, passing a `null` is a coding error, and I would throw an error to encourage developers to check the input before it is passed.

The problem with using checked exceptions is that too many developers ignore them. I am a fan of checked exceptions myself, but it only works when developers know how to handle exceptions.

Similarly, the problem with `Optional` is it's easy to ignore that Optional is not present and you don't get a message explaining why.

At some point you have to assume a developer will pick up they are using the API incorrectly and fix it.

Comment: Well, InputObject a is a bit complex (remember it's a network request) and adding that a set of specific fields is not null in the doc is leaking too many implementation details (I illustrated one example but the original method is a bit more complex).

Comment: @D-K When this error occurs, what would you feel is the idiomatic way to recover from this error.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. But I want to end the request gracefully. As mentioned in the question "catch it, inform the user that they did not set the appropriate field in the request & end the request" and maybe continue with some logging before returning.

Comment: @D-K Can you not do all that in this method? What do you feel only they can do?

Comment: I can end the request, but that would require passing in the request context. Also, I would still not be able to finish the code execution, as returning from this method does not end the calling method.

Comment: In that case, an exception is appropriate when you want to break the normal flow of control.  There is no checked IllegalArgumentException as normally this is not a retryable operation. When you have retryable operation, you normally need to have a specific Exception to make it clear what action needs to be taken and a something-went-wrong isn't enough information to know what to retry.